# Is it possible to change the default VSCode formatting settings for a particular language?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-formatting

I want to have VSCode indent C files by 2 spaces by default. Is it possible to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to @Batman's answer after you amended your question via a comment (since this is too long to put into a comment): look into "configure language-specific settings..." in your command palette.  It'll create

```
"[c]": {}
```

at the bottom of your settings.json so you can add anything there like:

```
"[c]": {

  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "editor.insertSpaces": true,
  "editor.detectIndentation": false
}
```

and that will only affect C files.

Answer (score 1):

> **File > Preferences > Settings**

Below Setting worked for me

```
"editor.tabSize": 2,
"editor.insertSpaces": true,
"editor.detectIndentation": false
```

[image: Code In Visual Studio Code]

Comment: How can I do this only for C files, and not for other types of files? If I'm editing a Java file, I want the spaces per indent to be 4.

Comment: Please take a look on @Mark's answer should work and solve your problem